# How to import a local package in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

Have a look at the error in the attached scrren shot.

`new` is the directory which contains `unittest` module of python 3.6 and `new2` contains `unittest` module of python 2.7. I understand the error raised in first case is because of missing `StringIO` module. But why python 2.7 is raising error despite writing the same command as in python 3. Is the syntax different in the two cases?

[image: Screen shot of terminal having error message]

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/your/file')
import your.lib
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `__init.__py` file. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

Comment: But since I have simply copied the `unittest` package, it has the '`__init__.py` which is there by default in every module.

Comment: Does `new2` contain the directory `unittest` or the contents of `unittest`?

Comment: It contains `unittest` folder. The contents are inside that directory.

Comment: So there is no `__init__.py` file under the `new2` directory so this is not compliant with python package structure. Try copying all the contents of `unittest` into `new2` directory and importing like you tried before.

Comment: @Alex Eschoo The import line would then need to change to `import new2`. Alternately, you could simply add an `__init__.py` to the folder `new2` (making it a module), and then use the same import line (`import new2.unittest`).